# Admin and Dashboard showing 404

Tags: craft3, apache

I am deploying a Craft site, I have it installed and everything is working fine, but whenever I try to access the admin panel I get a generic 404. I have tried every solution offered in similar questions, none of them work.
Here's my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

And my Apache Virtual Host file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin info@servername.com
    ServerName servername.com
    ServerAlias www.servername.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/servername.com/public_html/web/

        <Directory /var/www/servername.com/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
        </IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

Making the url hostname/index.php/admin does work, however.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated, or if more information is required please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, my url routing wasn't functional because the `mod_rewrite` module in Apache was disabled. I enabled it with `a2enmod`, restarted Apache, and my problem was solved.